# How to extend data source for pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm synchronizing data with an external database and the result is delivered to me on a sheet called *All Items*. Setting up a pivot table is easy. However, on the horizontal axis I need to display a custom value, computed from one of the columns in the externally linked data set.

When I go to *Analyze -> Change Data Source*, I can see that the currently regarded data area is called *'All Items'!Query*. I'd like to extend it by a column or two, so that my pivot table can display these values as well.

So, instead of *'All Items'!Query* as the data source I'd like to have *'All Items'!Query and the next two columns too*. I have no idea how to approach it nor what to try. Suggestions would be warmly appreciated.

I tried to define my own area called *'All Items'!Query_and_stuff* but the number of records retrieved during synchronization varies, so my extension needs to take that into the account. No idea how.

Comment: try the OFFSET formula, either in your reference OR in a new Named range that you create based on the original Query named range. something like `=OFFSET('All Items'!Query;0;0;ROWS('All Items'!Query);COLUMNS('All Items'!Query)+2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

`'All Items'!Query_and_stuff =  offset('All Items'!Query, 0,0 ROWS('All Items'!Query),COLUMNS('All Items'!Query)+2)`

Comment: @K_B Thanks, this might work. However, I'm not clear on how to define such a value. What I've done this far is to simply select the original data area **and by hand** add the two extra columns. Then, I just typed in the name in the box on the top left naming it. How do I go about defining the new area dynamically?

Comment: Depending on the version you are using: v2003 or earlier - Insert/Name/Define ...; v2010+ - select any cell and right-click and select 'Define Name'.

Comment: It works for a given run of the data synchronization. The problem is that when I update the data, the set might be longer (or shorter) and then I'll need to redefine the area manually. I need my user to just hit the update button and have the extended area to redefine itself. Is it at all doable?

Comment: Unless you have Automatic calculation turned off, the definition will redefine itself whenever the definition of Query is revised. Otherwise, you can issue an Application.Calculate command in a VBA Worksheet.Change event.

Comment: That'd be **perfect**! I'll try that out tomorrow at work. You're actually saying that if I design an area *Shazoo* by offset of *'Hazaa'!'Beep*, then *Shazoo* will get vertically longer if *Beep* gets vertically longer?! Cool stuff!